# A question about direct product

Tags: group-theory

Please see this proposition.

> Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $G_1,..., G_n$ such that $\mathcal{D}_1,\mathcal{D}_2,\mathcal{D}_3$ hold, then the mapping
>   \begin{align*}
> \alpha: {\huge\times}_{i=1}^n G_i\rightarrow G\text{ with }(g_1,...,g_n)\mapsto g_1\cdots g_n
> \end{align*}
>   is a isomorphism.
>
> $\mathcal{D}_1~~~~G=G_1\cdots G_n;$
>
> $\mathcal{D}_2~~~~G_i\trianglelefteq G;$
>
> $\mathcal{D}_3~~~~G_i\cap \prod_{j\neq i}G_j=1.$

It's a rather common proposition. But I'm stuck on one point when I tried to go through the proof.

**Question:**

$G_i\cap \prod_{j\neq i}G_j$ yields $[G_i,G_j]\leq G_i\cap\prod_{j\neq i}G_j=1$, which means for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$, $G_i,G_j$ centralizes each other. Since all $g\in G$ can be written as $g=g_1\cdots g_n$, then we'll have $$\boldsymbol{ gg^*=(g_1\cdots g_n)(g^*_1\cdots g^*_n)=(g^*_1\cdots g^*_n)(g_1\cdots g_n)=g^*g,}$$ where $g,g^*$ are arbitrary elements in $G$.

But it is utterly ridiculous, isn't it?

I'm a beginner in group theory, would you please give me some help and point out where I misunderstood? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $g_i$ commutes with $g_i^*$. That's not necessarily true if $G_i$ is nonabelian.

Comment: @Bungo Ah, yes! I feel like a fool... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should I delete this post? It this question valuable?

Comment: No problem. The rest of your argument, namely that elements of $G_i$ commute with elements of $G_j$ whenever $i \neq j$, is correct.

Comment: Someone might find it useful. I'll go ahead and write a quick answer so it doesn't have to stay open.

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much!

Comment: @Bungo ...$\ddot\smile$ well, what’s the reason I should choose...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reason.. You can accept the answer if it's satisfactory.

Comment: Ah, you don't have to close it. Accepting the answer (checkbox below the up/down arrows) will remove it from the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is almost correct: elements of $G_i$ commute with elements of $G_j$ *provided that* $i \neq j$. However, elements of $G_i$ need not commute with each other, since $G_i$ is not assumed abelian.

Comment: So the positions of $G_i$ can change, am I right?

Comment: If you mean that we can reorder the $G_i$'s in the product $G = G_1 G_2 \cdots G_n$, that is correct. In fact, you only need hypothesis $\mathcal D_2$ in order to do this: normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ always satisfy $HK = KH$, and by induction this holds for any finite number of normal subgroups. Your result is stronger: not only do the subgroups $G_i$ commute as sets, their individual elements also commute.